# Enabling CORS on Azure Active Directory

Tags: angular, typescript, azure, cors, azure-active-directory

I am trying to get a access token from Azure Active Directory programmatically using the following method in an Angular 6 application.

```
    let body1 = new FormData()
    body1.append("resource", environment.config.clientId)
    body1.append("grant_type", "client_credentials")
    body1.append("client_id", environment.config.clientId)
    body1.append("client_secret", "*****")

    return this._http.post("https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + environment.config.tenant + "/oauth2/token", body1)
```

I was able to retrieve an access token through this url in Postman but am blocked by CORS when calling it through my application. Error is below.

```
    Failed to load https://login.microsoftonline.com/*****/oauth2/token: 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-
Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 
'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.
```

So, how do I enabled CORS on the Azure Active Directory for all domains?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simple, you do not.

What you are doing is exposing your app's client secret to the public.
Remember that the request will be made from the *user's device*.
So they can observe it and capture your secret.
This is why the token endpoint does not support CORS, and probably never will.

UPDATE: The token endpoint does now support CORS, if you configure a reply URL with the SPA platform. This allows usage of Authorization Code flow with PKCE. MSAL.js 2.0 supports this flow. Note this still does not involve a client secret.

The way to acquire tokens from a front-end JS app is to use Implicit Grant Flow or Authorization Code flow with PKCE.
Or if you do need an app-only token, then you must do the request you tried from a back-end application.

Implicit grant flow allows you to get tokens directly from the authorization endpoint as the user signs in.
You can use ADAL.JS/MSAL.JS to assist in this.
You cannot have tokens without a user identity as your native app cannot prove its identity.

Comment: +1 To this answer. CORS is blocking you because you are trying to do something in a browser which you should *never* do in a browser.

Comment: Thanks @juunas for the information. I am using adal in my application for user sign in, but there is a part of the application where I want the user to be able to see some specific private without having to sign in (I am unable to make the data I'm trying to retrieve public) . This application isn't going to be deployed and is essentially a proof of concept, so I'm looking for a workaround to this issue. Do you know a way to programmatically login so the user wouldn't have to? With adal or not?

Comment: You will need a back-end for your app that gets the data and returns it for the front-end.

Comment: Hmmmm... What are supposed to do if we want to use PKCE flow on the browser? Hasn't the implicit flow been removed from recommended best practice?

Comment: I don't think PKCE is supported yet in Azure AD for this scenario. So implicit is the way to go for the time.

Comment: Or use cookies for front-end and do the auth in back-end

Comment: "The token endpoint does now support CORS" how exactly do you enable this?

Comment: You need to add a "SPA" platform to your app registration and add reply URLs to it.

Comment: Adding "SPA" almost worked since now prelight options request now returns OK. However, even though the preflight response has Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * , the browser still has error in console from origin 'https://localhost:44386' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: Are you using the new version of MSAL.js? https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/msal-browser