# Getting access token from Microsoft AD Application without redirection

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory

**Requirments**

I have created a Web API that requires access token from Microsoft Active Directory Application and then uses the access token in a subsequent request to Web API. I am consuming these Web APIs in my PowerApp components. However, I am unable to get the access token internally from Javascript without redirecting the user to the login page. As per my requirements, I have to get the access token and then access my Web APIs, without redirecting the user to login.

**Implementation**

I am making a POST call to "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tanent_id}/oauth2/token" from JS and trying to get the access token by using client secret.

**Issue**

I am getting the CORS issue whenever trying to reach the login API. I can get the access token from Postman and Internet Explorer but not to the rest of the browsers (i.e. Chrome, Firefox, Edge).

Can someone suggest me the way to prevent the CORS issue and proceed with my Web APIs calls with the access token. I have already learned the Implicit approach and it did not work since we need to redirect to URL in this approach too.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to use the client credentials flow? For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow

Comment: Yes, I have already done this too. In this case, it requires the authentication and redirects the application to the login Microsoft's login page that is not valid in my scenario. I have to get authentication and access token inside the app without redirecting to anywhere.

Comment: As far as I knew, if we use the client credentials flow, we can directly get Azure AD access token and we do not need to login. Could you please provide the code you use?

Comment: I am using the Client Secret flow and it seems it works for me but the issue is CORS. Whenever I try to request access token it keeps giving me the CORS issue. That is the main issue I am getting, I have searched a lot to get rid of this but I could not get any way.

Comment: Could you please provide the error picture?

Comment: Besides, is that you create a single page application?

Comment: It is basically PCF component but the point is, it is similar to SPA I am using Node and Typescript to get my work done. I have added the screenshot  Please check.

Comment: According to my research, we have no way to enable CORS on Azure AD.  For more details, please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52839055/enabling-cors-on-azure-active-directory

Comment: If the answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Implicit Grant Flow is not your option, and you do need an app-only token, I am afraid you must do the request from a back-end application. Then you can get the access token from the back-end application.

Comment: Yes this is the only way I have seen, However, the back-end application should be accessible through the Web API.