# Not getting refresh token and id_token with Azure AD OAuth2.0 ROPC flow using username and password

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I am using ROPC Flow with user details and client details to get Access token and refresh token. But I am only getting Access Token and this expires in 1 hour.

My frontend app has sign-in window where we provide AD user creds, this makes a post request and got FE with successful auth.

I have 2 questions:

1. Getting CORS issue while making user sign-in request using http://localhost:3000 with access-control-allow-origin header error.
2. I would like to get refresh token for Continues App login OR do I set the lifetime of the access token to a day.

REQUEST:

```
// Line breaks and spaces are for legibility only.  This is a public client, so no secret is required.

POST {tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
&scope=user.read%20openid%20profile%20offline_access
&username=MyUsername@myTenant.com
&password=SuperS3cret
&grant_type=password
```

RESPONSE:

```
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "scope": "api://94849942785375897059789375379/FIles.Read",
    "expires_in": 3598,
    "ext_expires_in": 3598,
    "access_token": 8YU4bMhafsfhaeoahehviyy8786w89ufo2ofj29h8gMWnB633NLWn7JQ"
}
```

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you .

Answer (score 1):

You need to add **offline_access** and **openid** to the scope parameter when requesting the token, try to add them, you will get the **id token** and **refresh token**.

[image]

**Update:**

Your application will need a back-end that will fetch the data and return it to the front-end. So try to call the token endpoint from the back-end .

Comment: Thanks, Carl,    Yeah, it got me id and refresh tokens.
Also as I am trying this auth from local node server while making POST request for  Token  I am getting access-control-allow-origin header error. How to resolve this CORS error for any host.

Comment: @adityaMehta  This is a very common error. You should not call the token endpoint on the front-end. Your application will need a back-end that will fetch the data and return it to the front-end. So try to call the token endpoint from the back-end . Here is a more detailed description for your reference:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52839055/enabling-cors-on-azure-active-directory.

Comment: Yeah Carl. Got you point and juunas too. Matter is I was making a unsecire call all way along.  Now will make this process by backend code level.

Thanks all for clearing on this.

Comment: @adityaMehta  Yes, it is very unsafe to call the token endpoint on the front-end.

Comment: @adityaMehta  Hi, If you still have any doubts, I will answer you as soon as possible.