# Can a browser app (spa) access MS Graph without a logged in user?

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-ad-graph-api

I can register an app in Azure as 'Web' application, specify the permissions it needs to read from Graph, consent to the permissions as an admin, create a client secret.

I try using the client secret in the app to request an access token. But MS identity platform rejects `grant_type=client_credentials` /token endpoint requests that come from a browser.

But how does it even know the caller is a browser? The same requests works when it is sent via Postman!

Obviously, CORS makes the difference: When a browser executes the request from myserver/myapp.js, it sets the 'Origin' header in the request going to login.microsoftonline.com and, by registration as a 'Web' app, does *not* send back an Access-Control-Allow-Origin response to the browser - the browser refuses to get the response. On the other hand, when Postman executes the request, it uses it's cloud agent to run the request. The agent doesn't send an 'Origin' header and doesn't check the response header.

Is there a different way an app in a browser can call Graph without a logged in user?

Comment: some argue that an spa must not use a client secret because it defeats security - true, but easily circumvented via a proxy like postman - securing the proxy or securing the secret seems equivalent to me

Comment: I am aware that an Azure app registration is either 'Web' (client can have secret, no CORS) or 'Spa' (client can't have secret, CORS)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is No. based on [this Azure AD official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-app-types#single-page-apps-javascript), if you want to get an access token on SPA, only `OAuth 2.0 implicit grant flow` and `OAuth 2.0 authorization code + PKCE flow` are supported but both of these two flows require users' interaction to login.

Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) is a browser mechanism. Your request is blocked by your browser, Azure AD endpoint does not care about what kind of app sends the request.

This is [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52839055/enabling-cors-on-azure-active-directory) answered by MVP: @juunas.